# How to change selected row in datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataadapter

I have another problem. I have binded datagridview, and when I doubleclick on row in it all cell values are "transformed" into textboxes. What I wanna do is when I change textbox value there also have to be made changes in datagridview and datatable. So far I get to change only first row of datagridview, not the selected. Here is my code:

```
private void buttonUredi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++j)
            {
               competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
            }

                }
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][0] = textStN.Text;
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][1] = textN.Text;
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][2] = textSN.Text;
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][3] = textC.Text;
                competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][4] = textYB.Text;
                this.grownsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                if (dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns] != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.BindingContext[competitorDataSet.Growns].EndCurrentEdit();
                }
                this.competitorDataSet.Growns.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int i = 0` as variable for the indexer in `DataTable.Rows` but you are never changing it.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++j)
    {
       competitorDataSet.Growns.Rows[i][j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
    }
    i++;
}
```

However, that'll change arbitrary rows in  the table, the first `dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count` rows. Is that desired?

Comment: If I do that, than the values from selected row is copied into very first row, the selected stayed the same, the "correct one" is the second one in my datagridtable, so there have to be another way, possibly completely different from which I took?

Answer (score 0):

Selected row number is stored in EventArgs e. Use it to locate selected row.

EDIT
I understand that you doubleclick row in dgv? If yes, you have something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

you can store the clicked row number like this:

```
int nClickedRow = e.RowIndex;
```

Comment: Yes, I already have this, but the nClickedRow is in another Method, so I can't use it in this: `private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)...`